# Showing that the function $f(a) = (1+a^{1+a})^a(1+a^{2a+2} - a^{2+a})^\frac{4+a}{2}> 1$ for $a \in (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a quick way in which one can prove the above inequality? I have tried taking the logarithmic derivative of $f(a)$ in order to show that the function is increasing on $(0,1)$, but things get tedious quite quickly.

Thank you.

Comment: a short look at the plot of the left-hand side shows that your inequality seems to be true.

Comment: Can you show us your calculations for the derivative of $\log f(a)$?